# Why is Spring Boot's resource precedence ignoring my external properties files?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, properties-file

As part of a Spring Boot project I need to load certain properties file which, by default, is located under de `src/main/resources` directory. Also, I need to be able to, instead, load an external properties file (located at the root directory of the project). If this external file exists, the file path should be passed as command line property.

The file structure would be like this:

```
/app_project
   Net.properties (external file)
   /src
      /main
         /resources
            Net.properties (default file)
```

The thing is that the dependency that makes use of those properties wouldn't work *unless* you copy/overwrite the contents of the external file into the file under the `/resources` directory.

**UPDATED**

So far I've tried:

- loading the file as an external resource and loading it into a Properties object (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)
- saving the properties as System Properties
- modifying the resource handler to look into other directories by overriding th `addResourceHandlers()` to include the location
- Explicitly including the location of the file in the CLASSPATH with the `-cp argument` (as @veysiertekin suggested)
- Loading it as a @PropertySource (as suggesed by @Nikolay  Shevchenko)
- Overriding the *Spring Boot's config location* with the `spring.config.location` (as suggested by @gWombat)

With all these methods I've tried, the file is indeed read and loaded but, at some point, and every time, the app resorts to the file under `src/main/resources` .

I suspect it may have to do with the precedence of the file (as described here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html), but I just couldn't figure out what's happening.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is your properties file copied to or in the same location as the actual location the jar is running from? If the jar is running from /app_project/target/ and your file is in /app_project, it won't find it.

Comment: @JoshMaag That's exactly the case; the `Net.properties` is in the root, and the .jar is under the `app_project/target/`. I'll try moving the file as you suggest and let you know. But...how come?

Comment: My understanding is that it's based on the location the jar runs from, which is in that target directory or target/classes/, so you need to make sure when your build happens that the properties file get copied there either automatically or manually.

Comment: That's exactly on point! So far we have been updating the manually (by using the `jar -uvf` commnad), how could it be done automatically?

Comment: If you're using maven, you could use something like maven-resources-plugin to copy it from an external folder (somewhere outside of the src/ directory for example). I'm sure you could find something similar for any build tool.

Edit: I just read you're using jar -uvf, that's not what I'm recommending. If you want it IN the jar, then just use the resources directory. If you want to OVERRIDE what is in the jar, then you should put the file in a directory next to the jar. So if the build jar is in /target/classes, put the properties file there.

Answer (score 0):

Try smth like

```
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource(name = "default", value = "classpath:default.properties"),
        @PropertySource(name = "external", value = "classpath:external.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
})
public class YourSpringBootApplication {
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've tried this and it behaves the same way. File gets read, properties loaded, but still, if the file under `src/main/resources` is empty, it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [official doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files), you can try to use the property`spring.config.additional-location` to add additional config file , or `spring.config.location` to override default file location.

You should pass those properties as program arguments so that Spring can use them on application startup.

Answer (score 0):

When spring-boot project is running, it checks files under the builded jar file. You need to add your external file to classpath before running the application:

```
java -cp 'path-to/spring-boot-application.jar:Net.properties' test.SpringBootApplicationMain
```